# java error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am running my solr on an `ec2` instance from `aws` and I have added my `solrj` libraries in a lib folder in my `solr` instance and added the path in the `solr.config`, but I still get the following error:

```
12-03 01:20:59.010: E/AndroidRuntime(5594):
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
Lorg/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient$Builder;
```

what else do i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

**Add solrj as libary :**

Gradle :

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj
compile group: 'org.apache.solr', name: 'solr-solrj', version: '6.3.0'
```

Maven :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: where do i add this?

Comment: In your Maven or Gradle build scripts ... of course.  But it assumes that you are using Maven or Gradle for your builds.

Comment: it is an android app and no build script has been written

Comment: In the build.gradle file inside dependencies tag

Comment: there is now build.gradle file i am not using android studio, using eclipse

Comment: Download solrj jar and all the compile dependencies https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj/6.3.0